# How to use a variable in Gherkin Datable

Tags: cucumber, bdd, gherkin

I am writing a scenario where I get an uuid as a response header of type Location which is passed to the step definition via Datatable. I need to use the same uuid again in the other scenarios. Is there a way where I can store a value in a variable in feature file? I am using godog

```
And the response headers MUST include:
  | Header       | Value      |
  | Content-Type | application/json |
And a location header
  | Location | <uuid> |
```

Comment: If you need to store a value from one step and use it in another step, that must be done down in the step definition.  I'm not sure what language you're using underneath, so it's hard to provide more specifics.  General note though, if you ever feel like you're "programming" up in the feature file, you might get a lot of value from stepping back and trying to push more detail down into the step def.  The purpose of the feature file as a BDD tool is to capture readable business rules, so it's good practice to keep them free of test implementation details (like uuid's).

Comment: I am using godog framework for golang. I already thought of using the step definitions to store the data, but just wanted to see if there is something that I could do in feature file as well. Thank you btw